# Why doesn't my php connect to sql database code work?

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server

/* I have set up a database in my php admin and use dreamweaver. Not sure 
why it doesn't work. The $ vars are taken from the ftp site i use. Here is 
the code: */

```
<?php
$db_host = "host";
$db_username = "user_name";
$db_pass = "password";
$db_name = "db_name";

@mysql_connect($db_host, $db_username $db_pass) or die ("Could not connect 
to MySQL");
@mysql_select_db($db_name) or die ("No database"); 

$sql = "INSERT INTO 'signups' (FirstName, LastName, email,CompanyName, 
JobTitle, ProductSector,ProductWebsite,ProductName,id)
VALUES ('$FirstName', '$LastName', '$email','$CompanyName', '$JobTitle', 
'$ProductSector','$ProductWebsite','$ProductName','$id')";
?>
```

Comment: miss [something](http://php.net/manual/it/function.mysql-query.php)? also the query contains syntax errors

Comment: Why do you silent errors?

Comment: ? sorry, but i am a noob. i checked this syntax sooo many times with different srcs and it appear correct. not sure where this is wrong...

Answer (score 1):

I realize this is a 'quick and easy' way to connect to MySQL - but it is extremely prone to [Sql injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). A [parameterized query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4712037/what-is-parameterized-query) is a more secure approach.  Additionally, the 'mysql' driver should not be used the driver is [deprecated and will not exist in php7](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php).  Instead, [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-connect.php) or [PDO driver](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php)(preferred) for sql is to be used. The MySQL_connect is no longer documented on the PHP website.

Even if this is a test environment, I would strongly encourage switching to a secure driver early.

As Elias Nicolas pointed out... Placing the @ symbol in front of mysql_connect causes any error you are having to be 'skipped'. The error won't log, and it will make it look like there isn't a problem when there is.

Edit: This will get you close to Mysqli - should already exist in the extensions for php.  You might need to enable it in the php.ini.  Also, you might need single ' marks around the ?'s. i.e: ('?').

```
// don't forget to sub the vars!
$db_host = "host";
$db_username = "user_name";
$db_pass = "password";
$db_name = "db_name";

$link = new mysqli($db_host, $db_username, $db_pass, $db_name) or die ('Could not connect to the database server' . mysqli_connect_error());

$sql = <<<QUERY
INSERT INTO signups 
    (FirstName, LastName, email, CompanyName, JobTitle, ProductSector, ProductWebsite, ProductName, id)
VALUES
    (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?);
QUERY;

if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql)) 
{
    $stmt->bind_param("sssssssss", $FirstName, $LastName, $email, $CompanyName, $JobTitle, $ProductSector, $ProductWebsite, $ProductName, $id);
    $stmt->execute();
}

$link->close();
```

Answer (score 0):

For your table name, and the names of the columns but not the values, you use ` instead of '. Your sql should look like this.

```
INSERT INTO `signups` (`FirstName`, `LastName` `email`, `CompanyName`, 
`JobTitle`, `ProductSector'`,`ProductWebsite`,`ProductName`,`id`)
VALUES ('$FirstName', '$LastName', '$email','$CompanyName', '$JobTitle', 
'$ProductSector','$ProductWebsite','$ProductName','$id')
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: thanks but this doesn't work. i have edited the quotes to be straight quotes and it still doesn't show. can we confirm that this is a syntax issue? is the rest of the syntax ok?

Comment: I believe that it is.

Comment: <?php
$db_host = "host";
$db_username = "user_name";
$db_pass = "password";
$db_name = "db_name";

mysql_connect($db_host, $db_username $db_pass) or die ("Could not connect 
to MySQL");
mysql_select_db($db_name) or die ("No database"); 

INSERT INTO 'signups' ('FirstName', 'LastName', 'email', 'CompanyName', 
'JobTitle', 'ProductSector', 'ProductWebsite', 'ProductName', 'id')
VALUES ('$FirstName', '$LastName', '$email','$CompanyName', '$JobTitle', 
'$ProductSector','$ProductWebsite','$ProductName','$id')";
?>

Comment: Look at my code exactly. The quotes are different at certain points. Look at the quotes extremely carefully.

Comment: thank you for your response. but even after direct c&p, it still doesn't work.

Comment: Are you putting the SQL into the $sql variable and then calling mysql_query($sql);